# Problems storing key in MS SQL db with C# Code

Tags: c#, sql-server

To get more familiar with both c# and ms sql, I made a key generator which is working good. But I want to store they key at a database so I made a method that runs a query and it should store the key(I thought)
This is my method:

```
        public SqlDataReader InsertInto(string tableName, string[] values)
    {
        string query = "";
        try
        {
            query = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " VALUES('" + values[0] + "')";
            for (int i = 1; i < values.Length; ++i)
                query += ", '" + values[i] + "'";
            query += ")";
        }
        catch
        {
            // ignored
        }
        return ExecuteQuery(query);
    }
```

And this is the code where I execute my query:

```
        private SqlDataReader ExecuteQuery(string query)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = null;
        SqlDataReader dataReader = null;
        try
        {
            using (connection = new SqlConnection(Hash.RunDecryption()))
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    using (dataReader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Failed to execute data! " + ex.Message, "Error!", System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            dataReader?.Close();
            CloseConnection(connection);
        }
        finally
        {
            dataReader?.Close();
            CloseConnection(connection);
        }
        return dataReader;
    }
```

And the query that is being generated is this `INSERT INTO Keys VALUES('fap0zkxbvw3')`
But I get the following error:

> Failed to execute data! Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: You need to understand the basic [SQL INSERT statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp).

Comment: @Win But when I do a new query in SQL server management it works just fine with the query it generates.

Comment: You should probably paramaterize this query.

Comment: InsertInto should not accept unlimited number of array. You need to provide the columns; otherwise it is a disaster waiting to happen. Besides, as Zane said you need to use parameterize query to avoid **sql injection attack**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The immediate problem is that you have 1 too many closing brackets:

```
query = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " VALUES('" + values[0] + "')";
```

should be

```
query = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " VALUES('" + values[0] + "'";
```

But you should really look into properly constructing your queries, using parameterizations, stored procedures, etc.